# What is the MKS Base AUX header connector type?

Tags: wiring, wire-type

I'm looking to crimp wires to the AUX-1 and EXP pins of my MKS base. For sanity reasons, i cant directly use Dupont jumpers, they keep coming out.

[image: MKS Base board]

*BIQU MKS-Base V1.6 Plate Controller Board for 3D Printer Ramps 1.4*

In the above product image, the type of housing is the "black" colored headers on the board, around the top left corner of the board. Each header has ~10 male pins inside of it

Most of the other pins are of JST-XH type, for anyone else wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a 2.54 mm pitch (similar pitch to Dupont) female IDC (insulation displacement connectors on a ribbon cable) connector of 2x5P (pins) for the header connectors that have a notch. (for comparison, note that e.g. RAMPS 1.4 has 2x5p dupont headers on the shield for the AUX headers, not the notch type headers)

[image: Flat ribbon connector]

These connectors are usually crimped onto flat ribbon cables and used to connect the display to the board. These connectors have a rectangular notch to fit the gap in the housing to correctly position the cable (which the 2x5P Dupont don't have).

[image: Flat ribbon cable, 10P (2x5P)]

For reference/difference, an image of the Dupont 2x4P and 2x5P is shown below, highlighting both sides ("up" on the left, "down" on the right):

[image: Dupont 2x4P and 2x5P]